# Android: send activity (this) to class in Thread not working

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I want to send `this activity` to `class` but not work

> main.java :

new Thread(new Runnable() {

```
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final LinearLayout lnrPost = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrPost);
                Cmd.readD(lnrPost, this);
                ......
```

> cmd.java :

```
 public class cmd {

        public static void readD(LinearLayout viewMain, Activity context) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                View viewIn = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post, null);
                ......
```

> Error :

```
 The method readD(LinearLayout, Activity) in the type Cmd is not applicable for the arguments (LinearLayout, new Runnable(){})
```

Comment: I was wrong with my answer, sorry @Mohammad. Check other answers, they are right. I misuntderstood the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error clearly mentioning that you are passing `Runnable` so

Change following line

```
Cmd.readD(lnrPost, this);
```

to

```
Cmd.readD(lnrPost, yourActivityName.this);
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thx, in cmd.java i use addview. but crashed app. viewMain.addView(viewIn);

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to send? Activity or Context?

If you want to send Activity, try

```
   Cmd.readD(lnrPost, MainActivity.this);
```

If you want to send Context, try

```
   Cmd.readD(lnrPost,getBaseContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code you are sending an object by referring this, which points to the current object which is the Runnable.
If you want to send the activity use

```
Cmd.readD(lnrPost, MainActivity.this);
```

If you want to send the context you can use the same method or use

```
Cmd.readD(lnrPost, getApplicationContext());
```

But I am wondering why your IDE didn't show an error before running..

Comment: His IDE did show that.
The error he mentioned is not a run time/compile time exception I guess.